# how to exclude certain pattern when searching in bash

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Let's say I have

```
 abc-def1-xxx
 abc-def2-yy-vv
 abc-def3
 abc-def4
```

I want to output `abc-def3` and `abc-def4`

If I use the pattern `abc-def*` then it outputs everything.
If I search for `abc-def*-*` then it out puts the first two entries
How do I get the last two entries?

Comment: What are those? lines in a file? or files in a directory?

Comment: The answers so far assume lines in a file; but if it's files in a directory, `abc-def?` will refer only to the ones you want. You could also use `abc-def!(*-*)` to refer to all files that start with `abc-def` but don't have any additional dashes past that point, if first you use `shopt -s extglob` to turn on extended globbing.

Comment: What is the pattern you are trying to match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the pattern more specific matching lowercase chars with a hyphen and matching 1 or more digits at the end

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-z]\+` Match 1+ chars a-z
- `-` Match literally
- `[a-z]\+` Match 1+ chars a-z
- `[0-9]\+` Match 1+ digits
- `$` End of string

For example

```
echo "abc-def1-xxx
abc-def2-yy-vv
abc-def3
abc-def4" | grep '^[a-z]\+-[a-z]\+[0-9]\+$'
```

Output

```
abc-def3
abc-def4
```

You could also match for example `abc-def` and then 1 or more digits:

```
^abc-def[0-9]\+$
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the data in put in a file, data.txt

```
abc-def1-xxx
abc-def2-yy-vv
abc-def3
abc-def4
```

The command to get the last two lines is:

```
grep -E '*[0-9]$' data.txt
```

Explanation:

- `-E`, the pattern is interpreted as an extended regular  expression.
- `*`: any character
- `[0-9]`: one digit
- `$`: ends with the character just before the `$`.  So here, it indicates that the string must end with a digit.

So it looks at the lines in data.txt, and outputs the lines where the last character is a digit, from 0 to 9.

Comment: what if it is not a one digit number

Comment: If the number has more digits, you could add a `+` after `[0-9]`.  A plus means 1 or more instances of the preceding character.  Here the character is one digit from 0 to 9.